# "Failed to build some targets" while Building Android Open Source Project (AOSP) for Dragonboard (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: build, ubuntu-16.04, android-source, ninja, android-soong

I'm trying to go through the procedure mentioned here on Ubuntu 16.04: https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/dragonboard/guides/aosp/ .
Since the steps before I face the error produce wide results and that I have run successfully, I am mentioning the step that I am facing the problem. Please note that the tutorial takes too much storage space.

When I try third step of Building the AOSP :

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

The error comes at around 97% as:

```
goroutine 689209 [runnable]:
android/soong/android.(*ModuleBase).computeInstallDeps(0xc058a41000, 0xa87f40, 0xc08bcb6b60, 0x9a51a1, 0x7, 0xc000024467)
    /home/Username/android_top/build/soong/android/module.go:628 +0x7c
android/soong/android.(*ModuleBase).GenerateBuildActions(0xc058a41000, 0xa87f40, 0xc08bcb6b60)
    /home/Username/android_top/build/soong/android/module.go:791 +0xec
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).generateModuleBuildActions.func2.1(0xc01a5c5980, 0xc08bcb6b60)
    /home/Username/android_top/build/blueprint/context.go:2303 +0x80
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).generateModuleBuildActions.func2(0xc01a5c5980, 0x0)
    /home/Username/android_top/build/blueprint/context.go:2304 +0x335
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).parallelVisit.func1.1(0xc0082e1500, 0xc01a5c5980, 0xc00e616360, 0xc00e616120)
    /home/Username/android_top/build/blueprint/context.go:1709 +0x30
created by github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).parallelVisit.func1
    /home/Username/android_top/build/blueprint/context.go:1708 +0x124
06:38:10 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
#### failed to build some targets (06:24 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Any possible reason why am I receiving this error? I am not able to find specific solution elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it was out of memory error. Nothing wrong with the code. Hope it helps if someone faces a similar problem!

Comment: It helped me again, haha.